# numeric differentiate: show that the relative mistake can be at 100%

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, numerical-methods

i have $f(x) = x+1$, a physical size, and the values $\tilde{f}(x_i)$ are measured at equally spaced points $$x_i=ih, \qquad 0 \leq i\leq 10^3, \qquad h=10^{-3},$$
with a maximum relative mistake of 0.1 %.

How to show, that when calculate the derivation $f'(x_i)$ with 
$$f'(x_i) \approx  \frac{1}{2h}(\tilde{f}(x_{i+1})-\tilde{f}(x_{i-1}))$$
there ist the possibility of a relative mistake of 100 %.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the approximation $\tilde{f'}(x_1)$ with your formula, assuming an error of $e=0.1\%=10^{-3}$ for  $f'(x_2)$ and  an error of $-e$ for the approximation $f'(x_0)$

$$\tilde{f'}(x_1) \approx  \frac{1}{2h}(\tilde{f}(x_2)-\tilde{f}(x_0))\\
= \frac{(1+2h)(1+e)-(1+0h)(1-e)}{2h}
= 2.001
$$
Because $f'(x_1)=1$, you have a relative approximation error of 
$$
\frac{|\tilde{f'}(x_1)-f'(x_1)|}{|f'(x_1)|} = \frac{2.001-1}{1} = 1.001 = 100.1\%
$$
If you compute $\tilde{f'}(x_k)$ for general $k$ with the same procedure you will get
$$\tilde{f'}(x_k) = 
\frac{(1+(k+1)h)(1+e)-(1+(k-1)h)(1-e)}{2h} = 
2+ 10^{-3}k$$